# Can't build maven project using different profiles

Tags: maven, properties, intellij-idea

I'm trying to build project through maven using different profiles.
I store data to connect to database in file `jdbc.properties`:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://${db.connectionURL}/shopsstore?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
jdbc.username=${db.username}
jdbc.password=${db.password}
```

And here is my `mvc-dispatcher.xml`

```
<bean id="propertyConfig"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
```

And `pom.xml`

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <db.username>root</db.username>
                <db.password>root</db.password>
                <db.connectionURL>localhost:3306</db.connectionURL>
                <db.driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</db.driverClass>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <db.username>prod-root</db.username>
                <db.password>prod-admin</db.password>
                <db.connectionURL>localhost:3306</db.connectionURL>
                <db.driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</db.driverClass>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

And when i run build i get following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'db.password' in string value "${db.password}"
```

Seems like properties are not available. Any ideas what's going on?
P.S I'm using Intellij IDEA

**EDITED**

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- specify UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or any other file encoding -->
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Enabling and configuring web resources filtering -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `maven-resources-plugin` to automatically update the  `jdbc.properties` during build based on the properties set in the profile.

Refer 
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

You have to set `<filtering>true</filtering>` to enable property replacement in the resources files

As you are using web resources,try changing the maven-war-plugin configuration to

```
<configuration>
 <webResources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
        <includes>
            <include>**/jdbc.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
 </webResources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i've updated my pom and got the same exception, please see edited question above, this how looks build section in pom.xml now